# Twitter Data Scraping with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape data from twitter with selenium. I wrote this code but `page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='tweet']")` line gives error.

And if I change to `driver.find_element` to `driver.find_elements`, this time `search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='SearchBox_Search_Input']")` line gives error.

I will write both errors. Somebody can help me? I'm about to go crazy.

1. If I write `driver_find_element(By.XPATH,.....)`, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[1], line 60
     57 scrolling = True
     59 while scrolling:
---> 60     page_articles = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='tweet']")
     61     for article in page_articles:
     62         tweet = get_tweet_data(article)
NoSuchElementException:
```

2. If I write `driver_find_elements(By.XPATH, ...)`, the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    
Cell In[2], line 46
     43 log_in.click()
     45 sleep(3)
---> 46 search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='SearchBox_Search_Input']")
     47 search_box.send_keys('Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu')
     48 search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
NoSuchElementException:
```

Here is my code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import csv

def get_tweet_data(article):
    username = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span").text
    nickname = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//span[contains(text(), '@')]").text
    try:  
        postdate = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//time").get_attribute('datetime')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return
    tweetText = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@data-testid='tweetText']").text
    reply_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@data-testid='reply']").text
    retweet_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@data-testid='retweet']").text
    like_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@data-testid='like']").text
    
    tweet = (username, nickname, postdate, tweetText, reply_count, retweet_count, like_count)
    return tweet

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

sleep(3)
username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='text']")
username.send_keys("dnmeztolga")

next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'İleri')]")
next_button.click()
my_pass = getpass()

sleep(3)
password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@name='password']")
password.send_keys(my_pass)
#password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
log_in = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Giriş yap')]")
log_in.click()

sleep(3)
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@data-testid='SearchBox_Search_Input']")
search_box.send_keys('Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

sleep(3)
people = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'En Son')]")
people.click()

data = []
tweet_ids = set()
last_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
scrolling = True

while scrolling:
    page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='tweet']")
    for article in page_articles:
        tweet = get_tweet_data(article)
        if tweet:
            tweet_id = ''.join(tweet)
            if tweet_id not in tweet_ids:
                tweet_ids.add(tweet_id)
                data.append(tweet)
     
    
    scroll_attempt = 0
    while True:
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        sleep(3)
        current_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
        if last_position == current_position:
            scroll_attempt += 1
            
            if scroll_attemps >= 3:
                scrolling = False
                break
            else:
                sleep(2)
        else:
            last_position = current_position
            break
```

I wrote what i expected and what i tried. I am new to this platform. Anybody can help me? I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more optimized working solution to your problem:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

def get_tweet_data(article):
    user = article.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-testid="User-Name"]').text.split('\n')
    name = user[0]
    username = user[1]
    postdate = user[-1]
    tweetText = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='tweetText']").text
    reply_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='reply']").text
    retweet_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='retweet']").text
    like_count = article.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@data-testid='like']").text

    return name, username, postdate, tweetText, reply_count, retweet_count, like_count

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = Chrome(options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")

username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="text"]')))
username.send_keys("your_username")
username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

password = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[name="password"]')))
password.send_keys('your_password')
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

search_box = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-testid="SearchBox_Search_Input"]')))
search_box.send_keys('Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[data-testid="tweet"]')))
data = []
tweet_ids = set()
last_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
scrolling = True

while scrolling:
    page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[data-testid="tweet"]')
    for article in page_articles:
        tweet = get_tweet_data(article)
        if tweet:
            tweet_id = ''.join(tweet)
            if tweet_id not in tweet_ids:
                tweet_ids.add(tweet_id)
                data.append(tweet)

    scroll_attempt = 0
    while True:
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        sleep(3)
        current_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
        if last_position == current_position:
            scroll_attempt += 1

            if scroll_attempt >= 3:
                scrolling = False
                break
            else:
                sleep(2)
        else:
            last_position = current_position
            break

print(data)
```

data:

```
[('Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu', '@kilicdarogluk', '8h', 'Şampiyonlar Ligi hazır.', '7,879', '21.6K', '130K'), (' ', '@herkesicinB', '9h', "Manisa da Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nun mitinginden dönen bir Kadını durdurup küfür ettikten sonra el hareketi çeken kişiliksiz Şehzadeler Belediyesi'nde Destek Hizmetleri Sorumlusu Sinan Öztürk olduğu ortaya çıktı. \n\nÇıldırmakta haklı , sermaye el değiştirecek..", '179', '1,233', '3,115'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Tired of generic fitness apps? Upgrade to MadMuscle and experience a personalized workout plan tailored to your goals and needs. From diet tips to exercise routines, our app has everything you need to succeed\n#MadMuscle #CustomFitness #PersonalTraining', '15', '20', '178'), ('HURMA', '@HurmaEdit', '13h', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu, Mısır'ı Türkiye'nin ili ilan etti.", '39', '331', '2,054'), ('尺1乙卂', '@rz_cerrahqasali', '11h', 'dün kemal kılıçdaroğlu “cambridge analytica” ile ilgili bir tweet atmıştı ve sosyal medya kumpasları olacağını söylemişti. biz de aylardır memleket partilileri uyardık. aranıza kripto akp’liler sızmış sizi gazlıyorlar diye. şimdi soruyorum, bunların gazına gelip de chp ve millet', '43', '647', '7,586'), ('Sıcak Medya', '@sicakmedya', 'May 1', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: "İlk Turda Bitirelim #Haydi"', '49', '776', '7,609'), ('23 DERECE', '@yirmiucderece', '13h', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nun Manisa mitingi sonrası evine dönen bir kadına, AKP standındaki bir erkeğin küfür edip el hareketi çektiği görüntüler ortaya çıktı.\n\n \n@dokuz8haber", '3,177', '5,937', '13.9K'), ("Türkiye'den Bilgi", '@TurkiyedenBilgi', '8h', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu bu kez evinin mutfağından Ali Babacan’la seslendi: \n\n“Şampiyonlar Ligi hazır.”', '8', '128', '347'), ('FuckTheSystem', '@fuckthesystem62', '15h', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nun, İletişim Başkanı Fahrettin Altun'a Cambridge Analytica uyarısı sonrası, uluslararası polis (Europol) dark web ağına baskın yapıp 288 şüpheliyi gözaltına aldı.\n\nDedem’i hafife alanlar biraz daha düşünün.  ", '29', '176', '890'), ('Alpay Özalan', '@alpayozalan35', '15h', 'CHP\'nin HDP bayrakları altında yaptığı Van mitinginde "Selo\'ya özgürlük" sloganları atılıyor. \n\nŞehit Yasin Börü\'nün ve tüm şehitlerin ahı, Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ve Meral Akşener\'in üzerine olsun.', '874', '1,802', '6,292'), ('HURMA', '@HurmaEdit', 'Apr 29', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nun seçmeni işte böyle olur ", '163', '914', '3,592'), ('BGY', '@bgyether', '12h', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nun Manisa mitingi sonrası evine dönen bir kadına, AKP standındaki bir erkeğin küfür edip el hareketi çektiği görüntüler ortaya çıktı.", '246', '456', '2,898'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Tired of cookie-cutter workouts? Our app creates personalized fitness plans tailored to your unique needs\n#FitnessCustomized #TailoredWorkouts', '25', '30', '206'), ('Türk Savunma Teşkilatı', '@tstyedek', 'May 1', 'İP’in yeni reklam filmini ben çok beğendim\n#TheEmperyalist \n#1MAYIS #kemalkilicdaroglu #MeralAkşener #yargı #Jahrein', '16', '415', '861'), ('debuffer', '@debuffer2', '7h', 'Ajans nasıl çalışır?\nKonu Recep Tayyip Erdoğan ve Devlet Bahçeli olunca Babala Oğuzhan Uğur: prompter yok o yüzden gelemezler\nKonu Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu olunca Babala Oğuzhan Uğur: adamın provokasyonla ilgili çekinceleleri var tabi', '55', '501', '1,517'), ('Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu', '@kilicdarogluk', 'Apr 28', '#HaydiTürkiye', '2,729', '19.5K', '129.6K'), ('Hazar Mailoğlu', '@hazarmailoglu1', 'May 1', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: 'Kemal Dede Çankaya'da çay içecek miyiz' diyorsunuz, söz içeceğiz. Benim saraylarda gözüm yok.\n\n#İlkTurdaTamam #SanaSöz", '242', '1,346', '10.5K'), (' ', '@militerdoktrin1', 'May 2', 'Devlet’in içinden Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’na ciddi bilgi akışı var. Kemal Bey’in gece yarısı attığı bu tweet boşuna değil.\n\nDevlet’in içinden Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’na uyarılar geliyor. O da bu uyarıları tweete döküp uyarıyor. Hükümetler yok olmaya mahkûm! Devlet ise ebedidir.', '64', '804', '7,056'), ('#HEDEF 2023', '@Yazi_Yorum__', 'Apr 29', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu', '92', '908', '5,497'), ('Bubayaiyi', '@islambulda', '11h', 'Hakan Bayrakçı, Muharrem İnce döneminde Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nun adamlarının, yine o dönemde Halk TV Genel Müdüru olan Şaban Sevinç’i arayıp aramadıklarını sordu', '2', '68', '131'), ('her şeyin peşinden koşan siyasetçi', '@Buse_gedikta', '40m', "CHP'liler takipe devam etsin GT yapıyorum. #KemalKılıçdaroğlu  ", '5', '', '29'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Get fit and stay motivated with MadMuscle - the ultimate workout companion for men! Track your weight, set goals, and crush your fitness routine\n#MadMuscle #Fitness #Workout', '5', '7', '91'), ('HaberLog', '@LogHaber', '15h', "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'na Van'da yoğun ilgi.", '24', '95', '706'), ('Bir Garip Ecevit', '@57_ilk', '12h', "Akp Van'da hakkın rahmetine kavuşmuştur.\n\n13. Cumhurbaşkanımız Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'na bir kalp bırakalım mı...?! ", '175', '619', '6,858'), ('hülya', '@HulyaElbl', '14h', 'Yolun bahtın açık olsun. Tüm kalbimizle enerjimizle ruhumuzla arkandayız, destekliyoruz güveniyoruz #KemalKılıcdaroglu\n#ilkturdabitirelim', '3', '26', '104'), ('Nazım.', '@NDirican1997', '23h', 'Geleceğini düşünen herkes sandığa!\nReklam arası bitiyor..\nAK çocuklar kaybedecek, AÇ çocuklar kazanacak.\nYeniden CUMHURİYET kazanacak.\n\nTürkiye Cumhuriyeti 13. Cumhurbaşkanı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu olacak.. \n\n#İlkTurdaKAZANACAK', '23', '287', '1,384'), ('İlknur İnce', '@ilknurince_MP', '9h', 'Sevgili muhalif arkadaşlarım. \n7 Mart\'a kadar hepiniz Cumhurbaşkanı adayı olarak Ya Ekrem İmamoğlu\'nu ya Mansur Yavaş\'ı istiyordunuz. 7 Mart\'ta Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu adaylığını açıkladı. \nBize gelince "21 yıldır bu dil,tavır var biz bu dilden,tavırdan bıktık" şeklinde ifadeler de…', '24', '73', '405'), ('Ebabil Kusu', '@Kusu__Ebabil', '8h', 'CHP’li Mine Kırıkkanat, \n\nCHP Genel Başkanı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ve ekibinin sansasyonel bir dosyası olduğunu açıkladı', '5', '104', '228'), ('Sekülerfobi Detected', '@sekfobidetected', '16h', "Bu insanlar CHP'ye karşı değillerdi. CHP ile aralarında bir duvar olduğunu düşünüyorlar ve CHP'nin onları dinlemeyeceğini düşünüyorlardı. O aradaki duvarı kaldıran kişi de Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu oldu. Bu görüntüyü görmemiz için ilmek ilmek işledi her şeyi. Razıyız.", '145', '1,222', '21.4K'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', "Whether you're a beginner or a pro, MadMuscle has everything you need to succeed. Get access to world-class trainers, nutritionists, and more\n#fitnesscommunity #trainhard", '2', '1', '11'), ('Twıtter bilgilendiriyor', '@twiter_bilgi', '16h', 'Cumhurbaşkanı Erdoğan:\n\n"Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu\'nu Cumhurbaşkanı adayı olarak karşımıza diken bir mekanizma var."\n\nEvraka:\nMekanızmayı buldum', '7', '12', '37'), ('CHP Konyaaltı Gençlik Kolları', '@KonyaaltiChpGK', '13h', 'Ninemizden Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’na mesaj var \n\n#SanaSöz', '3', '19', '128'), (' ', '@herkesicinB', 'Apr 30', "13'üncü Cumhurbaşkanı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu eşi Selvi Kılıçdaroğlu ile birlikte Gündoğdu Izmir de.. “Söz” dedi..", '22', '377', '3,249'), ('Berke İmamoğlu', '@BerkeeCHP', '19h', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu kazanacak ve ötvsiz F-35 alacağız', '3', '3', '59'), ('her şeyin peşinden koşan siyasetçi', '@Buse_gedikta', 'May 2', "CHP'liler takipe devam etsin GT yapıyorum. #KemalKılıcdaroglu  ", '54', '52', '440'), ('Türk Savunma Teşkilatı', '@tstyedek', 'Apr 30', 'Ne diyor bu edep yoksunu \n\n#izmir #GündoğduMeydanı \n#RecepTayyipErdogankazanacak \n#KemalKılıcdaroglu', '197', '532', '1,241'), ('PONÇİK BİRİ', '@PNCK25', '9h', "Muharrem ince Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’na ‘Fetö’nün yeni ortağı’demiş\n\nSormazlar mı adama iftira attığın adamla zamanında kol kola idin.\nO zamanlar değil de şimdi mi oldu?\n\nSHARMA'nın bir sözü vardır;\nBir insanın gerçek yüzünü seninle tüm menfaati bitince görünsün\nGördük yüzünü ince", '14', '69', '157'), ('Karargâh', '@karargah_haber', '10h', "Türk milletinin vergileriyle yayın yapan ve devlet kanalı olarak bilinen TRT'nin, seçim döneminde cumhurbaşkanı adaylarına ayırdığı süre: \n\nRecep Tayyip Erdoğan: 32 saat 42dk\nKemal Kılıçdaroğlu       : 32 dakika\nSinan Oğan                     : -\nMuharrem İnce              : -", '75', '436', '1,977'), ('Hindawi', '@Hindawi', '@Hindawi', 'Free to read, share and cite – our latest Article Highlights collection focuses on diagnostics, cell biology, and new treatments in optometry', '', '78', '85'), ('em.ir3734', '@em_ir3734', '14h', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nun Van mitingi\n\nVatan-Millet düşmanı “Chpkk” tescillenmiş oldu', '36', '128', '257'), ('Stratejist Galip İlhaner', '@Galipilhaner', '1h', "KAN döken ABD askerleri PKK (YSP)'ya oy vermek haramdır, caiz değildir.\n     HDP (PKK) ile seçim ittifakı yapan CHP ve Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'na oy vermek haramdır, caiz değildir.\n***  \n     Bir Müslüman, bile bile kan dökenlere (PKK-ABD),  oy veremez. Bu büyük bir vebaldir.\n     CHP…", '3', '5', '11'), ('Bülent', '@the_bulent06', '7h', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu rakibi yuhlanırken yuh yok diyor Tayyip Erdoğan rakibi yuhlanırken yuh yetmez diyor. Aralarındaki ahlak farkı bu işte.\n#İyigeceler ahlaklı insanlara', '8', '75', '295'), ('AA', '@Karacabeylii16', 'May 1', 'Erdoğan gitsin de kim gelirse gelsin dememiş. Helal olsun gerçek Atatürkçü böyle olur. \n\nSANCAKTARIMIZ ERDOĞAN.\n\n#KemalKılıcdaroğlu, Selvi, Portakal, Davutoğlu, Soda, Büyük BasınAçıklaması, Atatürk Havalimanı, Kalp, Şırnak', '89', '338', '1,170'), ('Mustafa Sarıgül', '@M_Sarigul', '10h', 'Bütün görevler biter, Erzincanlı olmak görevi hayatımın sonuna kadar devam eder. #CHP #Erzincan #SAnaSöz #kemalkilicdaroglu', '83', '357', '5,657'), ('Evil Wanda', '@master_missyy', '18h', "Melek Mosso'nun Isparta'daki konseri ahlak dışı olduğu gerekçesiyle Anadolu Gençlik Derneği'nin çağrısı üzerine iptal edilmişti. \n\nAnadolu Gençlik Derneği Saadet Partisi kuruluşu ve Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nu destekliyor.", '32', '234', '1,260'), ('Berke İmamoğlu', '@BerkeeCHP', '18h', 'Son Dakika : Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu osurdu\n\nMuharrem ince haklıymış', '3', '12', '193'), ('Nurullah Mese', '@NurullahMese1', '21h', 'Kemal kılıçdaroğlu seçimi %60 ile kazanacağız demiş. Bunu duyan ben ', '8', '17', '128'), ('Kaç Saat Oldu?', '@KacSaatOlduTR', '18h', "Ekrem İmamoğlu HDP ile bir olup Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu için şehir şehir gezerken İstanbul'da toplu ulaşım tamamen çöktü. Şimdi de İstanbul’da vapurlar korna basıyor, İBB’yi paraları alamadıkları için protesto ediyorlarmış.", '17', '893', '1,058'), ('Tazmania Canavarı 62', '@Tazz209xxxb', 'Apr 30', '#KemalKılıcdaroglu\nPeki ya bu fotoğrafın karizması kalitesi ', '41', '90', '1,409'), ('Polis Sendikası', '@turkpolsen', 'May 1', 'Polis de insan makine değil ! 24 saat nasıl çalışsın?\n#kemalkilicdaroglu', '52', '189', '1,040'), ('George A. Hamalian', '@gahamalian', 'May 1', "Turkish President Erdogan holds large rally in Ankara, Turkey's capital, 100s of 1,000s gathered to show support, ahead of May 14 presidential and parliamentary elections.\n\nHis main opponent, Kemal Kilicdaroglu, holds own rally of thousands in Izmir, West Turkey.\n@IntelRepublic", '', '2', '7'), ('ANKARA KUŞU', '@ankara_kusu', '19h', 'Son dakika.. DSP Tekirdağ Hayrabolu ilçe başkanı ve yönetimi ile birlikte 700 kişi partiden istifa ederek Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nu destekleme kararı aldı', '367', '2,193', '18.5K'), ('her şeyin peşinden koşan siyasetçi', '@Buse_gedikta', 'Apr 30', "CHP'liler takipe devam etsin GT yapıyorum. #KemalKılıcdaroglu ", '57', '96', '652'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', "Don't settle for average. With MadMuscle, you can unlock your full potential and become the best version of yourself. Start today\n#fitnessgoals #personalbest", '1', '3', '17'), ('Marginale', '@themarginale', '14h', 'Olaya bak. Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nun Van ziyaretinde kendilerini selamlayan vatandaşın annesine otobüs içinden küfür etmişler. \n\nBütün Chp’li troller de bu videoyu paylaşmış. Çok büyük rezillik.', '119', '545', '1,760'), ('Profesorfacia', '@Profesorfacia', '9h', 'Erdoğan: "Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu\'nu Cumhurbaşkanı adayı olarak karşımıza diken bir mekanizma var" demiş.\n\n2. ve 3. videolarda o mekanizmayı görüyorsunuz...', '32', '146', '406'), ('Who?', '@who98408150', '7h', 'Bıkmışız öfkeden, itibar adı altında görgüsüzlükten, yapmacık tavırlardan, halkı küçük görmelerden…Çok güzel özlenen görüntüler bunlar.\n#kemalkilicdaroglu #alibabacan #cokusdonemi', '77', '373', '5,479'), ('Yusuf', '@demirr_571', 'Apr 30', 'DEĞİŞİM" diyor. "ADALET" diyor. Sana söz yine baharlar gelecek diyor!\n#KemalKılıcdaroglu', '124', '737', '6,761'), ('Caner Güvener', '@CanerGuvener', '10h', "2018 milletvekili seçimlerinde Van'dan %2,6 oy alan CHP Genel Başkanı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu 'nun bugünkü miting öncesi Van halkı tarafından karşılanışı.....\nBay Bay Kemal mi \nBay Kemal Türkiye geneli %60 ile bu seçimi alır gibi ", '19', '85', '373'), ....,('Eylül', '@eylul_slck', 'May 1', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroglu: "Asgari ücretliden vergi almayacağız."\n\nAsgari ücretliler 1 yıldan fazladır vergi vermiyor. 1 Ocak 2022 tarihinden itibaren asgari ücretten vergi kesintisi tamamen kaldırıldı.', '3', '157', '326'), ('Buse', '@buseeyylmaz', '29m', 'Hadi be dedem yap şovunu #kemalkilicdaroglu', '', '', ''), ('Akın akın #EMAD', '@akinakin0764', 'May 1', '#kemalkilicdaroglu #BJKvGS #gündoğdu #2000LereSoezVerKılıcdaroglu oliveira Beşiktaş Salih Torueira #Gündoğdu #AnkaraicinDogrusuAkparti \n@herkesicinCHP\n \n\n2000 Sonrası 17 milyon SGK mağduru Seçmeni Yok Saymak \n\nBizi değil ama kendinizi Emekli Etmektir \n@Akparti\n @receptayyip207', '8', '82', '104'), ('Demokrasi', '@Halil330734', '25m', 'Halkın en çok güven duyduğu İstanbul Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Ekrem İmamoğlu’na ve Ankara Büyükşehir Belediye Başkanı Mansur Yavaş’a Cumhurbaşkanlığı görevi verilmesi  ve Cumhurbaşkanı adayı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ile birlikte mitingler tertiplenmesi halkta kabul gördü.\nTrabzon.…', '4', '7', '44'), ('Selin Savan', '@selinsavann', '16h', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu\'na Van\'daki karşılamaya bakın.\n\nÖyle yaka paça belediyelerden zorla toplayıp yoklama alarak götürdükleri insanlar değil.\n\nZaten belediye kayyumda...\n\n\n "TRT Genel Müdürü #dolar Nebati Mardin\'de 9" "Savcı Sayan"', '45', '135', '789'), ('Av. Alpay ANTMEN', '@avantmen33', 'May 1', '13. Cumhurbaşkanımız Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: "Aile Destekleri Sigortası Yasası\'nı çıkaracağız. Asgari ücretin altında veya hiç geliri olmayan aileler en az asgari ücret kadar parayı kadının banka hesabına yatıracağız. Devlet kadının güvencesi olacak." #sanasöz', '600', '15', '48'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Achieve your fitness goals with ease. Track your progress, stay motivated, and get in shape with MadMuscle! \n#fitnessmotivation #workoutgoals', '1', '5', '30'), ('Veli Ağbaba', '@veliagbaba', 'Apr 28', '13. Cumhurbaşkanımız Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: "Bütün köy okullarını açacağız. Ferhat ile Şirin\'in buluştuğu gibi öğretmenle, öğrenciyi buluşturacağız."', '152', '686', '2,452'), ('# Hüdayi #', '@hudayi_hh', 'Apr 30', 'Selahattin Demirtaşı Şeref Madalyası  Takarak Hapisten Çıkaracağım diyen  Sizin Cumhurbaşkanı Adayınız Oy İstediğiniz  Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ve size yemin olsun  bebek Katili Aponun Heykelini diktirmeyeceğiz  Ve Bu MİLLET sizi Kapatacak', '', '1', '7'), ('xfardos', '@xfardos', 'May 1', 'Daha önce Muharrem İnce\'ye oy vereceğini söyleyen Ahmet "Jahrein" Sonuç fikir değiştirdiğini söyledi: "Son zamanlarında yaptıklarından dolayı Muharrem İnce’den soğudum.\nOyumu Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’na vereceğim. Milletvekilliği’nde de İYİ Parti’ye vereceğim."', '', '2', '8'), ('SEÇİM 2023', '@depremm2023', 'Apr 30', 'Önümüzdeki günlerde Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu’nun yapacağı ters bir açıkmala ile 7’li masadan 1 kişi daha masaya veda edebilir…', '34', '5', '67'), ('ARZU TEKİN', '@arzuutekin', 'May 1', "Elinizi vicdanınıza koyun chp ye verilen her oy hdp yede gidecek\n\n#kemalkilicdaroglu Cumhurbaşkanı Erdoğan'dan Hakan Atilla #AyçaAyşinTuran #ilkTurdaTAMAM #CanYaman Sinan Oğan #KIZILELMA Bank Konya Ertan Saban Yavuz Türkiye Yüzyılı Taksim'e Barış Olağan Genel Kurulu AZ KALDI", '14', '74', '95'), ('Dedektif Joker', '@dedektifjoker', 'Apr 29', 'Ümraniye Ülkü Ocakları, Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ve Selahattin Demirtaş\'ın yüzlerinin birleştirildiği bir pankart astı. \n\n"Dikkat attığın her oy Mehmetçiğe kurşun olmasın" yazılı pankart Ümraniye\'liler tarafından indirildi.', '4', '1', '33'), ('Duygu Özen', '@Duygu82056405', 'May 1', 'Gördük nasıl Selam verdin Sivaslilara...Kemal Konyaya gider Konya bir devlet der.Siz de İzmire Sivas dersiniz.Allah bir insanı yoldan çıkmış kılmasın.\n#kemalkilicdaroglu\n#izmirmitingi\n#gündoğdu\n#Cumhurİttifakı\n#MilliGörüşMeclise', '7', '6', '22'), ('Ehliyet Affı Partisi', '@EhliyetPartisi', 'May 2', 'ŞoförBir Mayıstaİşsiz\n\nSayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu bugünkü Manisa mitinginde vaat verdi;\nGELİYOR GELMEKTE OLAN #EhliyetAffı !!!\n.', '30', '250', '371'), ('Birol Polat', '@Ankara06Birol', 'Apr 29', 'bu düzenlemeyi getirmeyecek iktidara da muhalefete oy filan yok. öyle bir günün cezası 17 sene olmaz.\n\nadalet şart! #kemalkilicdaroglu siz için biz varmıyız.\n\n#İkiBinlereSözVerKılıçdaroğlu', '', '36', '45'), ('S...İ...Y.. A...H', '@Anti__Depresan_', 'May 1', "1\nSonra diyorlar ki\nCIA bunun neresinde ?\n\n*\n#BenKemalGeliyorum\n#KemalKılıcdaroglu\nPortakal\nBizim Alevi'ye\nTRT Türk\nTeşekkürler Ankara\nŞirin\nKalp\nŞırnak\nYekta\nGültekin Uysal\nATV Avrupa", '3', '71', '155'), ('Seçim 2023', '@secimtr2023', 'Apr 30', '2023 Cumhurbaşkanlığı Seçimleri 2. Tur Anketi:\n\n %51,4 Recep Tayyip Erdoğan\n %48,6 Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu\n\n Optimar\n 25-28 Nisan 2023\n 3.005', '115', '63', '821'), ('SHU', '@shubeyyyy', 'May 1', 'Bartında milletle buluşan Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu Sosyal hizmet uzmanlarının önemini vurguladı\n\n"Nerede aile hekimi varsa orada Sosyal hizmet uzmanları da olacak"', '5', '75', '186'), ('Meltem TV', '@tvmeltem', 'May 1', "İşte Bağımsız Türkiye sözü\n\nBağımsız Türkiye Partisi Genel Başkanı Hüseyin Baş söz aldı , söz verdi  \n\nİstanbul 2 Meral Akşener Devlet Bahçeli #KemalKılıcdaroglu Trabzonspor Millet İttifakı #Cumhurİttifakı Bizim Alevi'ye #izmirmitingi", '8', '142', '350'), ('', '@YIGITBASKAN_RTE', 'Apr 29', '"Bunu o Masa’dakilerle birlikte yaptılar. Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ile birlikte yaptılar. PKK ile birlikte yaptılar. FETÖ ile birlikte yaptılar. \n\n“TÜRK VE SÜNNİ” ANA OMURGAYI OYUN DIŞINA İTME"', '', '5', '5'), ('DİNÖM Partisi Yenişehir İlçe Başkanlığı', '@dinom_mersinil', '16h', "Son zamanlarda Ychpli teyzelerin sık sık övdüğü, Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu'nun “HAPİSTEN ÇIKARACAĞIZ” dediği Selahattin Demirtaş kimdir?\n\nBuyrun izleyin, takdir milletindir…", '', '29', '51'), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Achieve your fitness goals with ease. Track your progress, stay motivated, and get in shape with MadMuscle! \n#fitnessmotivation #workoutgoals', '', '6', '41'), ("Türkiye'nin yabancı damatları", '@yabancidamat55', '8h', "14 mayıstan sonra Türk erkeklerini mutfağa tıkacağız gidip zenci sevgililerimizle oynaşacağiz. 14 mayısta feminist devrim için KK'ye oy ver #KemalKılıcdaroglu", '2', '4', ''), ('UT', '@UmutTopuz_', '7h', 'Ben kemal gelemiyorum. #kemalkilicdaroglu \n@kilicdarogluk', '', '', ''), ('veliduran', '@veliduran', '1h', '@kemalkilicdaroglu \n@meral_aksener\n@T_Karamollaoglu\n @alibabacan\n @Ahmet_Davutoglu\n @DpGultekinUysal\n \nTRT yayın rekoru.', '', '', ''), ('@Zelişş_', '@depdeli_Asena', 'May 1', 'Bu seçim pudracı çocuklar ile aç çocukların seçimi olacak !\n\n#KemalKılıcdaroglu\n#BayKemalGeliyor', '', '58', '168'), ('FOX HABER', '@FOXhaber', 'May 1', '#CHP Lideri #KemalKılıçdaroğlu: Açıkça söylüyorum orta sınıf yok edildi. Her sabah daha fazla yurttaşımız yoksulluğa uyanıyor.', '42', '133', '1,269'), ('Erkan AYDIN', '@erkanecz', 'Apr 28', '13. Cumhurbaşkanımız Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: "Bütün köy okullarını açacağız. Ferhat ile Şirin\'in buluştuğu gibi öğretmenle, öğrenciyi buluşturacağız."\n\n#SanaSöz', '56', '339', '313'), ('Ahmet Kaya', '@AhmetKayaCHP', 'Apr 28', ' Cumhurbaşkanı Adayımız Sayın Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu: \n\n"Bütün köy okullarını açacağız. Ferhat ile Şirin\'in buluştuğu gibi öğretmenle, öğrenciyi buluşturacağız."\n\n#KılıçdaroğluNeSöyledi \n#SanaSöz #KöyOkullarıAçılacak', '59', '431', '496'), (' /', '@fethullahgk47', 'Apr 29', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu sayesinde öğreniyoruz', '6', '', '10'), ('enginbayrak', '@engin0055', '11h', 'Reis bizler staj ssk mağdur larıyız senin hükümetin reis liğin döneminde adam yerine konmamış hakları teslim edilmemiş insanlarız bizleri görmedin #kemalkilicdaroğlu \nSesimizi duydu #StajyerinHesapGünüSandık', '', '2', ''), ('#sanasöz baharlar gelecek', '@neslipek66', '22h', 'İstiklal marşımız nasıl başlıyor \n\nKORKMA\n\nSeçimi kazanamazlarsa kaos çıkaracaklarına dair korku salmaya çalışıyorlar. \n\nHalkın gücünü birliğini görünce onlar korkacaklar.\n\n#haydi\n\n13.Cumhurbaşkanı Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu ', '14', '6', '73'), ('Erdal Nur', '@erdalnr', '11h', '13. Cumhurbaşkanımız Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu memleketime geliyor \n\n#Haydi Büyük Mersin mitinginde buluşalım.\n\n5 Mayıs 2023 Cuma\n13.30\nEski Tevfik Sırrı Gür Stadyumu Yanı', '6', '149', '1,425'), ('23 DERECE', '@yirmiucderece', 'Apr 29', '73 yaşındaki Ahmet Yılmaz, Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu\'nun Nevşehir\'deki mitingine katıldığı için imam Seyfullah Eker tarafından tehdit edildi:\n\n"Sosyal medyada linç kampanyası başlattılar, ağza alınmayacak hakaretlerde bulunuyorlar.  Bulunduğum kasabada camiye dahi gidemez oldum."', '362', '3,698', '15.2K'), ('Yuşa Övenç', '@Yusaisback', 'Apr 28', 'Kemal Kılıçdaroğlu neden mi İHA-SİHA’ları yok edecek?\n\nÇünkü ittifak ortakları onlara dokunulmasını ve bütün yatırımların durdurulmasını istiyor. \n\n#TEKNOFEST2023', '8', '300', '253'), ('GFB TÜRKÇÜ', '@kizilelma_gfb', '11h', 'Ben Kemal Geliyorum! #kemalkilicdaroglu', '', '', ''), ('MadMuscles', '@MadmusclesPlans', '@MadmusclesPlans', 'Are you tired of boring workouts and slow progress? MadMuscle is the answer! Get custom plans, real-time feedback, and endless motivation\n#fitnesstracker #workoutmotivation', '1', '4', '26'), ('Bulutaras', '@KemalHzarc2', '21h', '#EhliyetAffı\nŞoförünOyu Kılıçdaroğlu\nBiz bu düzeni degiştirecez', '', '29', '45'), ('Frederike Geerdink', '@fgeerdink', '17h', "do read this portrait of kemal kiliçdaroglu, by \n@louiseelisabet\n and additional reporting by \n@HillSevn\n - they travelled to kilicdaroglu's homeland #dersim and talked to his family. #elections #turkey", '3', '5', '11'), ('GercekNews', '@newsgercek', '21h', 'With just 12 days to go until the presidential elections, senior political scientist Bekir Agirdir believes that opposition candidate Kemal Kilicdaroglu has a higher chance of winning if there is a decrease in votes for Muharrem Ince and Sinan Ogan', '', '1', '1'), ('OSMANLI TORUNU', '@hakislamdavam', 'May 1', 'ABOVVVV NEDEN ERDOĞAN SORUSUNA ÖYLE GÜZEL KAPAKLIK CEVAP VERDİKİ. KAFASI BASAN SOLCULAR DİNLESİN#KemalKılıcdaroglu #Diyarbakır #BenKemalGeliyorum #Susmayacağız "Yılmaz Özdil" Selvi Ilgaz Sivas"Resmi Gazete\'de" Portakal Konya"İsmet Özel""İsmet Özel" Ukrayna Ceylin', '31', '130', '426'), ('@Zelişş_', '@depdeli_Asena', 'May 2', 'Bu seçimi FETÖ ile iş tutanlara ve PKK ile masaya oturanlara bırakmayacağız.\n\nDeğil mi  \n@varank\n ?\n\n#BayKemalGeliyor\n#HalkDevrimiBasladı \n#ilkTurdaTAMAM #KemalKılıcdaroglu', '12', '72', '155')]
```

Few things to note:

1. The attribute `data-testid="tweet"` lies in an `article` tag, not in a `div`. So you should use

```py
page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'article[data-testid="tweet"]')
# or
page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//article[@data-testid='tweet']")
```

instead of:

```py
page_articles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='tweet']")
```

2. It's always a best practice to use `WebDriverWait` instead of `time.sleep()` when we need to wait for certain web elements to get loaded or visible on the page.
3. As you might notice in the code I provided, we wait for the visibility of `username`, `password`, `search_box`, and `page_articles` elements to get located on the page using `WebDriverWait`.

I hope this solves your problem.